# What are the advantages and drawbacks of using long term private keys compared to session keys?

Tags: encryption

What are the advantages and drawbacks of using long term private keys compared to session keys?

Comment: Can you please be more precise / concrete with regards to the source of your confusion in your question? Right now, it would require a _very_ long answer to fully address all possible concerns.

Comment: Indeed, context would be useful (first thing that popped in my mind reading the question was forward secrecy)